# Azure Event Grid subscription validations for logic app

Tags: azure

I am creating event grid subscription with Custom delivery properties. I am setting the --delivery-attribute-mapping parameter when creating a subscription using the az eventgrid event-subscription create command.

Getting validation error. Validation token is not getting exchanged.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and support